# How to decrease billing tier required to run BigQuery query?

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like know how to decrease the billing tier requiered to run a query in BigQuery.  This is the error message that I am getting:

**Error running query: Query exceeded resource limits for tier 1. Tier 30 or higher required.**

The strange thing is it that a couple of weeks ago, I could run this query without any limitations. Nevertheless, today I tried the run the query twice, but I got two different errors.  The first attempt error asked for a tier 29.  Then the second attempt asked for a tier 30.  Why does the tier number continue increasing if the query is the same?

I read BigQuery's documentation and it seems that High-Compute limitations have been put in place ([link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#on_demand_pricing)).  However, this does not explain why the same query's limit has been increasing continously.

Could this be happening, because the data centers were working at their peak levels?  If this is so, can I run the query in batch mode in order to avoid having to change my tier levels (using the data center resources, when they are not at their peak)?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: can you include job ids for debugging?

Comment: Hi @FelipeHoffa, today I ran the query again and now the error message is: "Query exceeded resource limits for tier 1. Tier 44 or higher required".  The tier number continues increasing.  The job id for this case is: adept-storm-142922:bquijob_671e9413_158450ad43e